# Need group table view for Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Need iphone group table view(Username and password fields as in the screenshot)for Android application.

Can we able to design the same screen(having username and password with round corner,separated by a line, having key value pair as the in screenshot) in android app?If so, kindly share the code example.

[image]

Thank in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
in your layout file
Add this EditText's

```
<EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
                        android:layout_width="230dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg_siginusername"
                        android:hint="Email or username"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                        android:layout_width="230dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg_signinpassword"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:password="true"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
```

edittext_bg_signinusername.xml in your res/drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="@color/white" /> 
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/silver002" />   
  <padding android:left="6dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" 
      /> 
  <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
  android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

edittext_bg_signinpassword.xml in your res/drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="@color/white" /> 
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/silver002" />   
  <padding android:left="6dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" 
      /> 
  <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
  android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

By using this shape you will get the required output..
I hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

```
<TableLayout
    android:background="@drawable/username">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="Username" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="Pasdword" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

username layout would be like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="@color/white" /> 
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/silver002" />   
  <padding android:left="6dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" 
      /> 
  <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
     android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

similar to what pragnani has mentioned.